# Math not based on the 1 value

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hello is there any kind of math that is not based on the concept of 1 but only on continuous expressions? Maybe is this what vector are? If this question is stupid, answer me and I'll erase it.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to delete anything, ask away.

Comment: Any guess I might have as to what is being asked here would only be a guess.

Comment: Discrete mathematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I got you right: With the concept of $1$ you mean that things *are* or *are not*?

If that is what you meant then: Yes, it is called [Fuzzy Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_mathematics) (based on Fuzzy Logic) where the set of true values is $[0,1]$, or some other ordered lattice. However, this approach is still made from Classic Set Theory.

A fuzzy set on a set $X$ is a function $A:X \rightarrow [0,1]$, so $A(x)$ represents to what degree $x$ is an element of $A$. This covers the usual notion of belonging: If $A(X) \subset \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ (i.e. $A$ is a characteristic function) then for an element $x \in X$ either $A(x)=1$ and  it is in $A$ or $A(x)=0$ and  it isn't.

Comment: Yes maybe it's this , I'm reading the article thanks

Comment: Actually i'm bad at math writing i dont understand much of the expression I read (i know it's probably not hard..) but what I seek is maybe more along the idea of math where parameters have only a probability of being defined that is never 1 and never 0.

Comment: If I'm solving your questions (which I still don't truly know) then vectors have **nothing** to do with it.

Comment: If you want that the probability is never $1$ and never $0$ just think of the lattice $(0,1)$ and carry on with the construction.